# Regexp with python

Tags: python, regex

Service state: UP

Service state: UP | Falling 1/3

I need to put this in a conditional statement.

```
if line.startswith('Service'):
    result = line[2:].split()[2]
```

This only gives me "UP"

I need to be able to do -

`if service state == UP
then print ok
else
service state == UP.*
then print warning`

Basically a regexp with any occurrence of word after 'UP'

Comment: What happens if the service state be neither `UP` nor `UP` followed by something?  What gets printed then?

Comment: "How to write a regex that does X?" is not really an appropriate question for StackOverflow. You should try to do it yourself and if you have issues getting it to work, StackOverflow is the right place to ask questions about those issues.

Comment: Dont worry about that. It could be down or init. I can write elseif for other states. Only need the regular expression for UP and whatever follows the word UP is another state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something along these lines:

```
if line.startswith('Service state:'):
    result = line.split(': ')[1]
    if result == "UP":
        print("OK")
    elif result.startswith('UP') and len(result) > 2:
        print("warning")
    else:
        print("other case")
```

Note that we completely avoided invoking regex here, instead just using the base Python string functions to check with what the result begins, and how long it is, to determine if it matches `UP.+` (which, by the way, is the regex pattern you would want to use here).

Answer (score 0):

Using Python Regex

```
import re

line = 'Service state: UP | Falling 1/3';

if line == "Service state: UP":
    print("OK")
elif ((re.match(r'^Service state: UP.*', line))):
    print("warning")
else:
    print("others")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if line.startswith('Service state:'):
    result = line.split('state:')[1].strip() //newly
    if result == "UP":
        print("OK")
    elif result.startswith('UP') and len(result) > 2:
        print("warning")
    else:
        print("other case")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if line.startswith('Service')
    if line[line.find('UP'):] == 'UP':
        print('Ok')
```